# Django Queryset как создать такой запрос?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, queryset

Есть две таблицы
Товары и История цен
Необходимо из таблицы история цен выводить, последнюю стоимость по дате.
На Sqlite получатся, но не могу понять как это сделать через Queryset

```sql
SELECT name,max(date),price,price_discount FROM polls_products
INNER JOIN polls_history_price on polls_history_price.product_id = polls_products.id
GROUP BY polls_products.id
```

```
class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')

class HistoryPrice(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='price_list')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True,)
    price_discount = models.FloatField(blank=False)
```

Была попытка получить таким способом

```
Products.objects.prefetch_related('price_list').values('name','price_list__product_id').annotate(price_date=Max('price_list__date'))
```

но при добавление в values "price" он начинает попадать и в группировку, и тогда такой подход не имеет смысла

Comment: Покажите классы моделей

Comment: @Dmitry добавил

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

если вас беспокоит большое количество запросов к БД, но при этом ваш `SQL`-запрос вас вполне устраивает используйте `raw` [метод](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/)

Если же вас не устраивает `raw` метод, тогда пишите комбинированый запрос, используйте [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions), и класс [Max](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#max)

Для директивы `INNER JOIN` используйте метод `select_related()`

Здесь все таки напишу, что единственный запрос не означает его производительности, необходимо помнить, что запросы ленивы, ну, и пишите тесты.

Чтобы уточнить какой `query` у запроса есть соответсвующий метод, который можно использовать, для понимания какой запрос исполняется

```
print(any_q.query)
SELECT ...blablblabl....
INNER JOIN ....blblblblba.....)
```

**END UPD**

Для всех продуктов сущностей `product`

```py
from .models import Products
from .models import HistoryPrice

result =[]
products = Products.objects.all()
for product_ in products:
  inst = HistoryPrice.objects.filter(product=product_).ordered_by("date")[0]
  result.append(inst)
```

PS: писал с телефона, может ошибся где

Comment: слишком много запросов будет к БД

Comment: пытался так получить
Products.objects.prefetch_related('price_list').values('name','price_list__product_id').annotate(price_date=Max('price_list__date'))
но при добавление в values "price" он начинает попадать и в группировку, и тогда такой подход не имеет смысла

Comment: select_related - вроде бы как не подойдет, так же связь один ко многим?

Comment: @Evgen Вот вы написали запрос, выполните его и примените к нему метод `query` и вы увидите sql запрос и можно увидеть, что не так